# Laravel 5.6 and reflection not finding class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a package in Laravel 5.6, im very new to building packages so im cutting and copying and learning as I go. so far so good, except i have run into a little issue.

My main package class is in `packages/vendor/packagename/src/packagename.php`

In that file, it is using a foreach loop to loop over the classes which i have inserted into the config file, so for example, i have a controller in `app/Http/Controllers/TestController`

```
// $class in this case equals TestController
foreach ( $allclasses as $class ) {
    $classMethods = [];

    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass( $class );
}
```

When I run the code, i keep getting the following error;

```
Class TestController does not exist
```

The original code that i am copying this part from is found here https://github.com/Bulforce/laravel-ext-direct/blob/master/src/Bulforce/ExtDirect/ExtDirect.php at line 133.

I am taking the above code and building it for Laravel 5.6.

My TestController does exist. Im not sure whats going on. Is it trying to look for the controller in the `packages/vendor/packagename/src/` directory?

Im really stumpted ... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `$class` contain the full class with the namespace or just the name of the class?

Comment: @TheFallen It just contains TestController

Comment: I believe you need the class with the full namespace to be able to create it, otherwise it won't know where to find it. For example `\App\Http\Controllers\TestController`.

Comment: @TheFallen Oh that worked ... Thank you for that